# OBJ model not loading in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, three.js, 3d-model

I'm trying to load obj models, here's code (CoffeeScript)

```
loader = new THREE.OBJLoader manager 

if loadedModels.diamondRing == null

    loader.load "obj/diamond/ring1.obj", (object) ->

        object.traverse (child) ->
            if child instanceof THREE.Mesh
                child.material = silverMaterial.clone()

        object.position.y = 10
        object.scale.x = object.scale.z = object.scale.y = config.p1.size*0.05

        object.userData.ring = true
        combine.add object 

        loadedModels.diamondRing = combine.clone()


    loader.load "obj/diamond/diamond1.obj", (object) ->

        object.traverse (child) ->
            if child instanceof THREE.Mesh
                child.material = silverMaterial.clone()

        object.position.y = 10
        object.userData.diamond = true
        object.scale.x = object.scale.z = object.scale.y = config.p1.sizeDiamond*0.075

        combine.add object
```

But I caught exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined obj.js:93
```

where obj.js - THREE.OBJLoader.

on line 93 placed add_face function:

```
    function add_face( a, b, c, normals_inds ) {

        if ( normals_inds === undefined ) {

            geometry.faces.push( face3(
                vertices[ parseVertexIndex( a ) ] - 1,
                vertices[ parseVertexIndex( b ) ] - 1,
                vertices[ parseVertexIndex( c ) ] - 1
            ) );

        } else {

            geometry.faces.push( face3(
                vertices[ parseVertexIndex( a ) ] - 1,
                vertices[ parseVertexIndex( b ) ] - 1,
                vertices[ parseVertexIndex( c ) ] - 1,
                [
 -- line 93 -->     normals[ parseNormalIndex( normals_inds[ 0 ] ) ].clone(),
                    normals[ parseNormalIndex( normals_inds[ 1 ] ) ].clone(),
                    normals[ parseNormalIndex( normals_inds[ 2 ] ) ].clone()
                ]
            ) );

        }

    }
```

I think problem in normals, but i dont know where exactly. 
Reading model problem happened on last lines, like this:

```
 f 6802//6802 6803//6803 6804//6804
```

If in obj model remove affected lines:

[image: enter image description here][1]

In 3d editor model look normal.
May be someone faced such problem.

Comment: Do you know which model is the problem? Have you tried just loading the model (without doing the scaling and other stuff)? Have you tried it with standard javascript? What 3d program are you using? Are you exporting the .obj from the 3d program or are you doing some sort of conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing standard obj loader to this https://github.com/maxogden/stl-obj-viewer